# Get Internet Explorer stream with SHDocVw DLL

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, shdocvw

I use this code to open a web site:

```
private void OpenBrowser(string url)
{
    object sender;
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e;
    ie.DocumentComplete += (DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler) 
        new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        wb = (IWebBrowserApp) ie;
        wb.Visible = true;
        object o = null;
        wb.Navigate(url, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);

}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, ref object e)
{

}
```

the web site was opened but I want to access to document stream of that web page for access page's content. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the document object model as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341(VS.71).aspx